# Move/Respawn multiple game objects to original position after player dies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move multiple games objects to the original position, after the player dies. That is the following code, but I don't know, why it is not working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class respawn : MonoBehaviour
{
 public lvlmanager Lvlmanager;
 public GameObject[] resetObjekt;

 private Vector3[] originalPosition;
 private Quaternion[] originalRotation;
 private Rigidbody2D[] objektBody;

 private void Start()
 {
     Lvlmanager = FindObjectOfType<lvlmanager>();
     for(int i = 0; i < resetObjekt.Length; i++)
     {
         originalPosition[i] = resetObjekt[i].transform.position;
         originalRotation[i] = resetObjekt[i].transform.rotation;
         objektBody[i] = resetObjekt[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
         Debug.Log(originalPosition[i]);
     }
 }
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
 {

     if (other.tag == "player")
     {
         Debug.Log("player dead");
         Lvlmanager.RespawnPlayer();
         for (int i = 0; i < resetObjekt.Length; i++)
         {
             objektBody[i].velocity = Vector3.zero;
             objektBody[i].bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Static;
             resetObjekt[i].transform.position = originalPosition[i];
             resetObjekt[i].transform.rotation = originalRotation[i];
             objektBody[i].bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;
         }
     }
 }
 }
```

When I start the game, it shows following error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object respawn.Start () (at Assets/script/respawn.cs:21)

Anyone knows, what the problem is?
Those objects are platforms that fall, that's why I use kinematic etc.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't/shouldn't simply reload the scene?

Comment: Yes, I use checkpoints. Just want to move specific objects to the start position, so the player can try it again, without doing the whole level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`originalPosition`,`originalRotation` and `objektBody` is never assigned to.

Before referencing them in `Start()` you should do

```
originalPosition = new Vector3[resetObjekt.Length];
originalRotation = new Quaternion[resetObjekt.Length];
objektBody = new Rigidbody2D[resetObjekt.Length];
```

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment. I got it. Thank you very much! :-)